# Does my 6-month UK visa start from when I enter the UK in August or from the issue date in June?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-expiration

I have a 6-month visa to enter the UK starting June 8th. Do my 6 months start when I enter the UK in August or from the start of June? The visa expires on December 8th. If I enter in August, can I stay till February?

Comment: Can I change the start date? move it back 2 months

Comment: When you applied, did you tell them you had plans to stay six months?

Answer (score 1):

The date your visa expires is the last date you are allowed to be in the UK, whether you enter 6 months before or 1 day.

Comment: Can I change the start date? move it back 2 months. I'm in Thailand

Comment: @Mike You can’t change the actual start date once the visa has been issued but you can of course enter later than that. There are certain circumstances in which you can extend the visa from in the U.K. https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules